# how to insert a node in a middle of a linked list in cypher

Tags: neo4j, linked-list, cypher

I am using linked list pattern in cypher to represent some data.

`(node1)-[:NEXT]->(node2)-[:NEXT]->(node3)`

the question is how can I insert `newNode` between the linked list nodes. so that I get

`(node1)-[:NEXT]->(newNode)-[:NEXT]->(node2)-[:NEXT]->(node3)` for example.

there are some corner cases where the `newNode` can be at the end of the list or the beginning and the solution needs to account for them.

is there an elegant end easy way to do it without multiple apoc.do.when calls?

Comment: This knowledge base entry can help probably https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/creating-and-working-with-linked-lists/

Comment: thanks but i'v seen that one. they are giving basic examples for creating a linked list but not inserting or deleting nodes.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is plumb in the new node, and then remove the old relationships, something like... (I'm assuming some properties here)

```
MATCH (n1:Node {name:'node1'})-[r:NEXT]->(n2)
CREATE (n1)-[:NEXT]->(:Node {name: 'new Node'})-[:NEXT]->(n2)
DELETE r
```